# Split string by delimiter and skip parts where delimiter followed by some character

Tags: c#, .net, regex, split

Is it possible to use Regex.Split() to split a string by a delimiter, but only if delimiter not followed by some character.
For instance I would like to split a string by the ":" delimiter, but ignore the ":=" delimiter. This code:

```
string input = "One : Two:Three:=Four";
string pattern = @":";
Regex reg = new Regex(pattern);
var parts = reg.Split(input):
```

returns 4 parts : "One", "Two", "Three" and "=Four".

I tried to modify the sample like this:

```
string input = "One : Two:Three:=Four";
string pattern = @":[^=]";
Regex reg = new Regex(pattern);
var parts = reg.Split(input):
```

Now I get 3 parts: "One", "Two" and "hree:=Four". What has to be changed in the pattern to get also the start of the third part correctly, like this: "Three:=Four".

What about extending the above example with an additional start/end delimiter definition that disables also the split by the defined delimiter. For instance:

```
string input = "One : Two:Three:=Four {Comment:String:="This is a comment";AddditionalInfo:String:="This is some additional info";}";
```

The result should contain the following 3 parts: "One", "Two" and "Three:=Four {Comment:String:="This is ...}".

I mean the ":" delimiter should be ignored if present between the "{" and "}" delimiters.

Comment: `where delimiter followed by some character` you know `space` is too a character.

Comment: @RickyTad please check my answer and the demo.

Comment: see my edited answer. and please note that making big changes to question makes the previously correct answer incorrect, so please edit question if there is an error in your question, and not change or extend it, you may ask another question for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
:(?!=)
```

So your code should be like:

```
string input = "One : Two:Three:=Four";
string pattern = @":(?!=)";
Regex reg = new Regex(pattern);
var parts = reg.Split(input);
```

For the second part of your question, you may first choose to remove those between `{}` and then split them:

```
input = Regex.Replace(input, @"\{[^}]*\}", "");
```

[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LE9QxL/2)

Comment: The first part of the question is solved, thanks. Regarding the second part of the question: the string between {} has to be parsed separately later, thus cannot be deleted directly. How could this part be first extracted before getting removed?

Comment: well, you don't have to really remove it, may be put the altered string in another variable or just: `reg.Split(Regex.Replace(input, @"\{[^}]*\}", "")).`, your input value does not change but it the part in `{}` in the split string, and please note that it might be possible to do both in one regex (i don't know how) but its not fine to write a very complex regex that takes lots of time to execute just to avoid doing it in two lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can split with:

```
:(?!=)(?![^{]*})
```

Comment: Thank you for answering to the second part of my question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a negative lookbehind `(?<!` and a negative lookahead `(?!` to assert that the colon is not between curly braces.

To make sure that the colon is not followed by an equals sign you could also use a negative lookahead.

`(?<!\{[^{}]*):(?!=)(?![^{}]*})`

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5c%7b%5b%5e%7b%7d%5d*%29%3a%28%3f!%3d%29%28%3f!%5b%5e%7b%7d%5d*%7d%29&i=One+%3a+Two%3aThree%3a%3dFour)

**Explanation**

- `(?<!` Negative lookbehind to check what is on the left is not

  - `\{[^{}]*` Match `{` followed by matching 0+ times not `{` or `}`
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `:(?!=)` Match a colon if what follows is not an equals sign
- `(?!` Negative lookahead

  - `[^{}]*}` Match 0+ times not `{` or `}` followed by matching `}`
- `)`

Using your example, that would look like:

```
string input = "One : Two:Three:=Four";
string pattern = @"(?<!\{[^{}]+):(?!=)(?![^{}]+})";
Regex reg = new Regex(pattern);
var parts = reg.Split(input);
```

[Demo C#](https://ideone.com/Tszn9R)